# How to select features for random forest using varImp function?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I have applied random forest on a training data which has about 100 features. Now I would like to apply feature selection technique in order to reduce the number of features before applying random forest model on the data. How can I make use of varImp function (from caret package) to select important features? I read that varImp itself uses some classification method to select features (which I found very counter intuitive). How exactly can I apply varImp to get important subset of features which I then can use while applying random forest classification algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `caret` package author Max Khun on [feature selection](http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html):

> Many models that can be accessed using caret's train function produce
>   prediction equations that do not necessarily use all the predictors.
>   These models are thought to have **built-in feature selection**

And `rf` is one of them.

> Many of the functions have an ancillary method called `predictors` that
>   returns a vector indicating which predictors were used in the final
>   model.

If you want to retrieve importance score in your model, add `importance = TRUE` in your `train()` call

> In many cases, using these models with **built-in feature selection will
>   be more efficient** than algorithms where the search routine for the
>   right predictors is external to the model. Built-in feature selection
>   typically couples the predictor search algorithm with the parameter
>   estimation and are usually optimized with a single objective function
>   (e.g. error rates or likelihood).

Comment: I have two doubts. (1) What if I use `ranfomForest()` function from randomForest package instead of `train()` from caret? Will it still take care of automatic feature selection for me? (2) How would I use some other feature selection technique using `varImp()` (say PLS), before applying `randomForest()`? Also, would that be effective?

Comment: @Sangram 1) `radomForest()` has `rfcv` (Random Forest Cross-Valdidation for feature selection). This function shows the cross-validated prediction performance of models with sequentially reduced
number of predictors (ranked by variable importance) via a nested cross-validation procedure. You can also refer to `importance`. This is the extractor function for variable importance measures as produced by `randomForest` 2) If you still want to do feature selection out of the model, you can use whatever technique you want.